Flutter GetX Obs data not showing in first build
Why my UI widget not showing data after the first build? But when navigate to other screen and back to HomeScreen, the widget will show data (User widget at top)? Is there anything I missed?
My app demo video
Here is the Homescreen code:
class HomeScreen extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    HomeController controller = Get.put(HomeController());
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
                Obx(() {
                  return SimpleUserProfile(
                      profileImageUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/200',
                      profileUsername:
                      controller.studentData.value.name ?? 'studentName',
                      profileUserID:
                      controller.studentData.value.studentId ?? 'studentId');
                }),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

And this is homescreen controller I made:
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  late final HomeService _homeService;
  late final AuthController _authController;
  late final StudentMapper _mapper = StudentMapper();

  late Rx<StudentEntity> studentData = StudentEntity().obs;

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    _homeService = Get.put(HomeService());
    _authController = Get.find();
    await getStudent();
  }

  Future<void> getStudent() async {
    var token = _authController.getToken();
    var studentId = _authController.getStudentIdFromBox();

    final response = await _homeService.fetchStudent(
        _authController.getToken(), _authController.getStudentIdFromBox());

    if (response != null) {
      studentData = _mapper.toStudent(response).obs;
      studentData.refresh();
    } else {
      Get.defaultDialog(
          middleText: 'User not found!',
          textConfirm: 'OK',
          onConfirm: () {
            refresh();
            Get.back();
          });
    }

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(response);
      print(token);
      print(studentId);
      print(studentData.value.studentId);
    }
  }

  @override
  void refresh() {
    studentData.refresh();
  }
}

I tried using Obx, but nothing changed. Is there something I forgot to add to the code?

When you extends your class with "GetView", you don't have to manually use "Get.put" inside build method. you can directly access it. So, try to remove the "Get.put" from your build method and the remaining code will be the same then try to run again.

i'm sorry, i forget to change again to StatelessWidget after some experiments. thank you for your guidance!.

What I noticed is the studentData, since it is an observable variable so you need to use it like this:
studentData.value = _mapper.toStudent(response);

By assigning the data using studentData.value, it triggers the UI to update when the data changes.

Nice, thank you.
Its solve my problem, the data show right after the ui is build.
